# How to use ImageJ with NetBeans

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I have `ij` jar file. How can I adopt the help of this jar file in my code.

I want to create an `image auto selection tool`.

Is `ij` or `javacv` better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open NetBeans and add the first Library: Tools -> Librarias -> New Library.
2. Give the name of ij Library Name and click OK
3. Click the button Add JAR / Folder and then browse for the jar files that you want and select OK.
4. Next add the Component Pallet Library: Tools -> Palette -> Swing / AWT Components.
5. Click the new category and name ij.
6. Select ij then click Add from the Library -> ij -> Next -> select all the components palette -> Next -> ij -> Finish

by doing this you will add your jar file and also use it to your project using Netbeans

Comment: It was very intresting & helpfull..thanks a lot...Now i am working with an image processing project .so, i am expecting some more tips from you

Comment: why not always most welcome.....

Answer (score 0):

Open Netbeans, In the projects window where there are packages and files of your project. There there is one folder named Libraries, Right click that, and then click on Add Jar/Folder, then choose the ij.jar file. Hence you will be able to use your ij.jar file in your coding.

Another way to do is explained by @Yousuf Umar.